# Boost shared_ptr dereference cost

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

I am trying to compare performance between raw pointers, boost shared_ptr and boost weak_ptr. On the dereferencing part, I expected shared_ptr and raw_ptr to be equal, but results show that shared_ptr is about twice as slow. For the test, I am creating an array with either pointers or shared pointers to ints, and then dereferencing in a loop like this:

```
int result;
for(int i = 0; i != 100; ++i)
{
  for(int i = 0; i != SIZE; ++i)
    result += *array[i];
}
```

The full code for the test can be found here:
https://github.com/coolfluid/coolfluid3/blob/master/test/common/utest-ptr-benchmark.cpp

Test timings for an optimized build without assertions can be found here:
http://coolfluidsrv.vki.ac.be/cdash/testDetails.php?test=145592&build=7777

The values of interest are "DerefShared time" and "DerefRaw time"

I guess the test may be flawed somehow, but I failed to figure out where the difference comes from. Profiling shows the operator* from shared_ptr gets inlined, it just seems to take more time. I double-checked that the boost assertion is off.

I would be very grateful if anyone can explain where the difference might come from.

Additional stand-alone test:
https://gist.github.com/1335014

Comment: +1, I was thinking about this the other day too.

Comment: Cache effects? shared_ptr is bigger than a raw pointer, so your array will cover more cache lines and take longer to read.

Comment: What platform are you running these tests on?

Comment: All test runs were done on x86_64 linux. Tested compilers were GCC 4.5 and 4.6, and clang 2.9. Boost was 1.46.1 in all cases, the linked timings are for GCC 4.5.

Comment: Why an array of pointers? Shouldn't you be dereferencing the *same* pointer many times?

Comment: @Emile I didn't want the compiler to optimize the whole thing away, using an array seemed the safest way for that. But I am open to suggestions for better testing procedures than what I have now.

Comment: @BartJanssens: I'll pass. Regular criticism is easier than constructive criticism. ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Alan Stokes said in his comment, this is due to cache effects.  Shared Pointers include a reference count, which means they are physically larger in memory than a raw pointer.  When stored in a contiguous array, you get less pointers per cache line, which means the loop has to go out to main memory more often than it would for a raw pointer.

You can observe this behavior by, in your raw pointer test, allocating `SIZE*2` ints, but also changing the de-reference loop to stride by `i+=2` instead of `++i`.  Doing this yielded approximately the same results in my tests.  My code for the raw test is below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/timer.hpp>

#define SIZE 1000000

typedef int* PtrT;

int do_deref(PtrT* array)
{
    int result = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i != 1000; ++i)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i != SIZE*2; i+=2)
            result += *array[i];
    }

    return result;
}

int main(void)
{
    PtrT* array = new PtrT[SIZE*2];
    for(int i = 0; i != SIZE*2; ++i)
        array[i] = new int(i);
    boost::timer timer;
    int result = do_deref(array);
    std::cout << "deref took " << timer.elapsed() << "s" << std::endl;
    return result;
}
```

Incidentally, using `boost::make_shared<int>(i)` instead of `PtrT(new int(I))`allocates the reference count and the object together in memory rather than in separate locations.  In my tests this improved the performance of shared pointer dereference by about 10-20%.  Code for that is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/timer.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#define SIZE 1000000

typedef boost::shared_ptr<int> PtrT;

int do_deref(PtrT* array)
{
    int result = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j != 1000; ++j)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i != SIZE; ++i)
            result += *array[i];
    }

    return result;
}

int main(void)
{
    PtrT* array = new PtrT[SIZE];
    for(int i = 0; i != SIZE; ++i)
        array[i] = boost::make_shared<int>(i);
    boost::timer timer;
    int result = do_deref(array);
    std::cout << "deref took " << timer.elapsed() << "s" << std::endl;
    return result;
}
```

My Results (x86-64 Unbuntu 11 VM):

```
Original Raw: 6.93
New Raw: 12.9
Original Shared: 12.7
New Shared: 10.59
```

Comment: "_Shared Pointers include a reference count,_" actually a pointer to a data structure with 2 ref counts, a pointer, a deleter, and maybe even a mutex (hopefully not).

Comment: @curious The size is 2 pointers - one to the real payload, one to the overhead. But none of that affects the cost of a simple deterrence.

Comment: Ah, many thanks! I will adapt my test to make the comparison more fair.